# Outdoor outlet tripping all other outlets when used

Tags: wiring, receptacle, outdoor

As of about two days ago (admittedly a heavy storm) if I connect any device to my outdoor outlet, it'll trip not only that socket but also the only other outlet attached to this circuit. The main breaker doesn't flip, but the only way I can reset the outdoor outlet is to also reset the other, indoor, outlet.

I am thinking the outdoor socket is hosed, but was curious if anyone had any other ideas...

Comment: Are these both GFCI outlets?

Comment: What did you plug in? Perhaps that device/object has a ground fault and the GFCI is supposed to be tripping in that case.   Why BOTH GFCIs are tripping is a second issue unrelated to what us causing one to trip.

Answer (score 2):

If rain is getting into the box from outside, you could put a new rain resistant cover on the outlet which might solve the problem.

If there is a leak into the box that you cannot immediately stop, then you can remove the receptacle and wire the circuit through with wire nuts. This will prevent this one spot from tripping a GFCI breaker or receptacle. Wire nut connections are much more resistant to moisture than a receptacle.

I had to do this for a receptacle on an outside wall which was getting wet from a roof leak into the wall and tripping an essential circuit protected by a GFCI breaker. I used regular Scotchlok (red size) wire nuts, filled them with antioxidant paste, and turned the nuts upward so they would shed water. I attached a blank cover plate over the box.

Comment: If you want to try simply a new cover, when the old cover is off use a hair dryer to dry out the box before putting on the new cover. You don't need to move the receptacle for this. Just keep it moving and don't overheat the receptacle or the interior of the box.